# vim disable spelling in certain regions

Tags: vim

When writing latex in vim in the tabular enviroment, example

```
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  one & two \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{what?}
\end{tabular}
```

the `rl` is flagged as a miss spell but it should be ignored.
I have added the following to after/ftplugin/tex.vim:

```
syn region texMyNOHL matchgroup=NONE start='{tabular}{' end='}'
    \ contains=@NoSpell
```

but it is still marked as a miss spell.

What would be the correct way of ignoring the specific mentioned region?

Comment: Good question, but better suited for superuser.com.

Comment: It has been discussed previously that questions related with vim go in stackoverflow. why is this question different from other vim questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just "overlay" your `texMyNOHL` region; the existing tex syntax definitions prevent a match, because they are finer-grained.

When inspecting the syntax, you'll see that the item is matched by the `texMatcher` group. This one allows to include inner matches via the `texMatchGroup` syntax cluster:

```
:syn match texRl contained contains=@NoSpell "rl"
:syn cluster texMatchGroup add=texRl
```

Comment: If I understand your answer this would consider "rl" not to be miss spelled even outside the tabular contruction. Is this the case?

Comment: The `texMatcher` group represents stuff like `{...}` and `[...]`; it applied in all those things. I've added `contained` to the answer to make this more clear, but for Tex this doesn't seem necessary, as the entire document is contained in a top-level group.